# Google OAuth Redirect Uri Mismatch (authorization_code)

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, google-oauth

I am having a problem to understand the correct purpose of the redirect uri. Following the Google tutorial the javascript API allows me to get a authorizationCode without any redirect URI at all.

Then I send this code to my server and try to call the /token endpoint with this code. But then it will return a "redirect URI mismatch" which probably means that I need to define the same redirect_uri for this endpoint than I did with the javascript API. My only problem is that I dont specify any on my website.

Anyone knows how to correctly use them?

The flow I am trying to achieve is the following:
- Javascript website asks user for permission, getting the authorization code
- Code is sent to my server
- Server receives access/refresh token with this code and stores it safely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The flow I am trying to achieve is the following: - Javascript website asks user for permission, getting the authorization code - Code is sent to my server - Server receives access/refresh token with this code and stores it safely"

This can't be done. Google will not issue an Auth Code to a JavaScript client. To do so would be a major security problem. You will need to write server code to request offline access, which will get you the Auth Code and Refresh Token you're looking for.

Your app can still be a JavaScript SPA (if that's what you're aiming for), but you'll need to serve the app from an app-server (Java, PHP, etc) to handle the offline aspects of the auth.

As an alternative, you can do the whole thing in JavaScript, but you will not have a Refresh Token. If your app is solely JS, that shouldn't be a problem and will be transparent to the user. The gapi library deals with obtaining Access Tokens as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The point of a redirect uri is to tell the authentication server where to return the authentication code.

**Installed Application**

If i have an installed application Windows for example it knows to just return it to the same place it came from.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code
```

The above link will display an auth window to the user and the authentication code it returns will be sent back to exactly where the request came from.

**Web Application**

In the case of a web application. What is the location the request is coming from? Its the clients pc? Which is just a web browser running your web application. The client cant handle the authentication code your web-server must have a file on it which can handle the authentication code.

Adding a redirect uri of `http://webapplication120170125114757.azurewebsites.net/authorize/` tells the authentication sever to return the authentication code to your website so it can be dealt with.

**redirect URI mismatch**

Miss match means that the redirect uri that you put in the link above is not one that you have registered in Google developer console.  It must match exactly including any port numbers.

**Js Origin**

If you're using the JavaScript client, you need to set a valid JavaScript origin for google to authorize you.

Authorized redirect URIs are the endpoints they going to call as a callback if you're using 3-legged OAuth 2.0 flow. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#webserver

Comment: the redirect uri is registered inside the google console, i managed to get it working with the form submit method, where both redirect uris where the same (authorize and token endpoint). the problem here is that with the javascript popup i dont need to specify a redirect uri

Comment: with JavaScript you have the Js origin its different.

Answer (score -1):

Please pass your javascript origin in the "redirect_uri" parameter when you are exchanging the code. This should work.